# HVFloat, caption below table

Tags: tables, floats, captions, rotating

I would like to use the rotated table with the caption bellow the table. Unfortunately, the following code does not work. Thanks for your help....

```
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\hvFloat[floatPos=!h,rotAngle=90,capPos=t,capVPos=c,capWidth=w,floatCapSep=10] {table}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
A & B\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
3 & 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please post complete documents that reproduce the error or at least state where you have defined the commands used. `\hvFloat` isn't a standard command (and not in a package I know)

Comment: I don't know `hvFloat` and since there is no compilable example, i cannot test anything. But what happens if you change `capPos=t` to `capPos=b`?

Comment: @ David, Johannes: 3 additional packages included, sorry for omitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}
    \hvFloat[floatPos=!h,rotAngle=90,capPos=b,capVPos=c,capWidth=w,floatCapSep=10]
    {table}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline 
            A & B\tabularnewline
            \hline 
            \hline 
            1 & 2\tabularnewline
            \hline 
            3 & 4\tabularnewline
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}}
        {Text}{label}

    \end{document}
```